# Sitecore Lucene:Indexing issue with content delivery servers

Tags: lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8

I have two content delivery servers s1 and s2 and several indexes.For each index I have used two indexing strategies :

1. OnPublishEndAsync strategy
2. RemoteRebuild strategy

Whenever I publish the item through content editor , the data is getting updated only on one server (i.e. s1) and the other server(s2) still displays the old content.In the logs I can see that for the server which is still displaying the old content, there are no indexing jobs running.After server restart everything works fine and all data gets visible.

Also, suddenly for some time interval no indexing jobs are running for both the servers. This is not happening simultaneously on both the servers. At one particular time indexing jobs are not running for only one server and another server is working fine.

**Note:** Currently I am using Sitecore 8 update 6

I am not able to find what is causing this issue.

Comment: This may help you - http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/search_index_troubleshooting/ .

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your scalability settings and also your eventQueue. You need to make sure that your eventQueue is enable.

Now when an index is being rebuild, you can go to the Core database from SQL server, query the most recent entries. You should have something concerning event trigger index:start. There is a field called InstanceName. This will show on which instance the index rebuild has been triggered. You should have both CD servers.

Also, check the Core replication job from CM to CD if you are using one.

You can read more about how to setup the scalability setting from my blogpost: 
https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/sitecore-scalability-setting/

Also, one main point to check is to see if your servers are synchronized. When they are not in sync, the different events take time to trigger on the un-synchronized server since the events have not been triggered. You can read my post on the Sitecore Server Synchronization at https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/sitecore-server-synchronization/

Thanks